# How to resolve NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException in spring with error expected single matching bean but found 2 while using factory patterns

Tags: java, spring

I have created a factory pattern which gives me the service I should be using for the task. Earlier there was only one service and everything worked well.

But now I am adding one more service and I am getting the error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException
```

I have tried using `@Qualifier` and `@Resource` annotations to fix this issue as suggested in other answers over here. But it didn't help.

```
 public interface IService { 
     public PerformTask();
 }
```

---

```
 @Service
 public class ServiceA implements IService {
     public PerformTask(){};
 }
```

---

```
 @Service
 public class ServiceB implements IService {
     public PerformTask(){};
 }
```

---

```
 public interface IServiceProviderFactory {
     IService getService(Task task){}
 }
```

---

```
 @Service
 public class ServiceProviderFactory implements IServiceProviderFactory {

    @Autowired
    private ServiceA serviceA;

    @Autowired
    private ServiceB serviceB;

    @Override
    public IService getService(){
        if(task=="A")
            return serviceA;
        else
            return serviceB;
    }
 }
```

---

```
 @RestController
 @RequestMapping("/myService/api/v1")
 public class myServiceController {

    @Autowired
    private IService iService;

    @Autowired
    private IServiceProviderFactory ServiceProviderFactory;

    @PostMapping("/task")
    public ResponseEntity performATask(@RequestBody Task task){
    this.iService=ServiceProviderFactory.getService(task);
    this.iService.PerformTask();
    return new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.CREATED);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Exception tells you that Spring don't know what bean to inject into your `myServiceController.iService` (you have 2 beans which implementing this interface). In your case, I suggest removing this field completely, because you don't need it there. Besides, there is no sense assigning `@Autowired` field iby yourself.

```
 @RestController
 @RequestMapping("/myService/api/v1")
 public class myServiceController {

    @Autowired
    private IServiceProviderFactory ServiceProviderFactory;

    @PostMapping("/task")
    public ResponseEntity performATask(@RequestBody Task task){
    ServiceProviderFactory.getService(task).PerformTask();
    return new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.CREATED);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You definitely can specify a bean and resolve ambiguity having `@Qualifier` (or even specifying a correct name of the concrete implementation).

But in your example it doesn't make sense to `@Autowire` a service, and then reassign it.

You may face possible concurrency issues there. Despite you may not use multithreading explicitly, majority of application servers allow concurrent requests. So having the second method here which tries to get a `IService` from `IServiceProviderFactory` and assign it to a shared `private IService iService` object instance may lead to inconsistency and wrong service resolution.

Moreover this is waste of resources. Why ask Spring to resolve something if you will throw it away in a moment?

This is how it suppose to be if you need manipulate `IService` in the method:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/myService/api/v1")
public class myServiceController {

    @Autowired
    private IServiceProviderFactory ServiceProviderFactory;

    @PostMapping("/task")
    public ResponseEntity performATask(@RequestBody Task task) {
        final IService iService = ServiceProviderFactory.getService(task);
        iService.performTask();
        return new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }
}
```

Otherwise you can get rid of `IService` reference as was proposed in the first answer.